# Best Practice? Transparency of Entity Framework/Linq2sql in Business Layer

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, architecture

I'm into a little migration from traditional DataSets and of course continue go through BL. How do best I create a single class in BL that's acts like a transparent class, for data that are requested from application & not need to be managed differently then it already is in DAL?

Is there some major violation in this idea?

Comment: Well done. Moving away from DataSets and TableAdapters was the best thing we ever did.

Comment: I can fully agree with that. But it also ships with a little confusing of much functionality down in DAL, that feels messy to reproduce.. Until now I just worked with projects that tooked datacontext into the business layer.. which just make validations and business objects looks messy..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at using [POCOs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) with [Entity Framework 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/05/21/poco-in-the-entity-framework-part-1-the-experience.aspx). The linked blog post is a really good starting point.

Comment: Thank's. I'm really Not a starter on the topic. And you send links to two completely different things, which don't put usefull info when used together (which the question is about).

Comment: The two links are certainly related. You can send back POCOs from Entity Framework 4. This is a big step-forward for Entity Framework, and I'd really recommend looking at that when you want to refactor your data access layer.

Comment: Related, not useful. The more i look deep into this, i got a stronger feeling that there are not so much more flexibility of Entities then DataSets? I have to create inserts, deletes, getsByAnyId(blabla) methods even here.. the dbml/edml models that are so super generic..

Comment: Using POCOs is a massive step-forward. DataSets have almost (ok there are always exceptions) no use anymore. POCOs are certainly more flexible, to take one example, your POCOs will contain business validation logic, which is exactly where you want it to be. Yes, you need methods to update and create new entities but that's what any data access code will need.

Comment: Keep learning about Entity Framework 4, you'll learn to love it. :)

Comment: business logic in pocos, well yeah that's not to belaud ef for.. lol. Count me right. 1. i'm pleased to kick out this ugly datasets. 2. I DONT want to redo codes everywhere, which are already generic implemented onced in EF/linq2sql (upd/ins/del). 3. Please - i know pocos and EF.. I have to get it right (Together).